# Understanding a joke in Zwiebach - "A first course in string theory"

Tags: string-theory, terminology, compactification

So fairly early on Zwiebach discusses the quantum mechanics of a one-dimensional square well. He then goes on to add an extra dimension which is compact to demonstrate how one can understand compactification (Page. 38 of the 2nd edition).

When introducting this extra dimension, turning the one-dimensional square well into a two-dimensional one, he says

> "*We now add an extra dimension to the square-well problem (no pun intended!).*"

**What is the pun?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about physics.

Comment: It's perhaps not physics, but I'm also curious. Could it be that "to add an extra dimension" to a problem [means](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100885) to make it more complex/rich? Or that the pronunciation of *square-well* is similar to that of *squirrel*?

Answer (score 4):

The two meanings of dimension that make it a pun:

1) A spatial dimension

2) A layer of complexity